# Is it possible to make an input type number fit to the width of the number it's displaying?

Tags: html, css

Would it be possible to do something like this:

```
.input[type=number] {
    width: (width of the number inside of the input field)
}
```

Comment: with only CSS: no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKay, here's how I fixed it:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.myInput');

input.addEventListener('input', () => {
  text = document.createElement("span"); 
  document.body.appendChild(text);
  text.innerHTML = input.value; 
  
  width = Math.ceil(text.getBoundingClientRect().width); 
  inputNumber = width + "px";
  input.style.width = `${inputNumber}`;
  
  document.body.removeChild(text); 
})
```

```html
<input type="number" min="1" max="100" value="1"  class="myInput" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant do it with css, but easy can implement it with JS;

For example:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.myInput');

input.addEventListener('input', () => {
  const inputNumber = input.value;
  
  input.style.width = `${inputNumber}%`;
})
```

```html
<input type="number" min="1" max="100" value="1"  class="myInput" />
```